# Using KenodUI and IgniteUI in the same page

Tags: jquery, grid, editor

I have an IgniteUI Grid and a KendoUI Editor (the editor for this grid)

I wanted to write a condition based on the data that exists in one column of the IgniteUI grid but I am getting a Jquery error ("ul" undefined) when I base the condition on KendoUI drop down list.

I couldn't embed KendoUI and IgniteUI in the same code.

Here is my example

```
$("#contactGrid").on("iggriddatabound", function (event, ui) {
            var i, grid = ui.owner,
                ds = grid.dataSource,
                data1 = ds.data(),
                dataLength = data1.length;

            for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {

                if (data1[i]["cntRelation"] !== "Will Maker 1") {
                    var dropDown = $("#cntrelationID").data("kendoDropDownList");
                    (dropDown.ul.children()).hide();
                    (dropDown.ul.children().eq(0)).show();
                    (dropDown.ul.children().eq(1)).show();

                }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?